# Serial Communication Errors: IllegalStateException & IOException

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I have a program that connects to a USB device, the USB device is a consumer product and it works fine using their software and using PuttY, it's a fairly simple Serial communication using strings. (per their documentation).

I am having a problem with some of my code, specially when trying to do something with the **read-string other than just display it**
I'll try to be as clear as I can on what's going on:

1. First the software scans for available COM ports (this works) and
   populates a list
2. Second, the user selects a COM port and connects to it (This works), opens up the COM port, and initializes a listener and an I/O
   stream
3. Third there is an event listener that constantly updates a user-visible log with the data is receiving (this works fine as
   well)

HOWEVER! there is a button that starts performing a test, this test enables a boolean "testinprogress" that makes the listener perform a different task on data-available additional to displaying what it's reading.

Here is the code for the eventlistener:

```
@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    if (evt.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE)
    {
        if (testProgress == true)
        {
             try
            {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                TemperatureParser parser = new TemperatureParser();
                TemperatureReading reading;
                output.flush();
                reading = parser.parse(reader.readLine());
                readings.add(reading);
                textLog.appendText(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            statusLabel.setText("@serialEvent.IF Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")");
            System.out.println("@SerialEvent.IF Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                fullLine = reader.readLine();
                textLog.appendText(fullLine + "\n");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            statusLabel.setText("@serialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")");
            System.out.println("@SerialEvent.ELSE Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, here is the problem, IF I comment out the following lines, the read-then-display thing works fine:

```
            reading = parser.parse(reader.readLine());
            readings.add(reading);
```

These two lines are related to a special class created for this project (Credit to James_D):

```
//SPECIAL CLASSES NEEDED
    public class TemperatureReading {
        private final double[] values;
        private final LocalDateTime timeStamp;

        public TemperatureReading(LocalDateTime timeStamp, double... values) {
            this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
            this.values = new double[values.length];
            System.arraycopy(values, 0, this.values, 0, values.length);
        }

        public TemperatureReading(double... values){
            this(LocalDateTime.now(), values);
        }

        public double getValue(int channel) {
            return values[channel];
        }

        public int getNumberOfChannels() {
            return values.length;
        }

        public LocalDateTime getTimestamp(){
            return timeStamp;
        }

        public boolean noneExceed(double max) {
            return DoubleStream.of(values).allMatch(v -> v <= max);
        }
    }

    public class TemperatureParser {
        public TemperatureReading parse (String text) {
            return new TemperatureReading(Stream.of(text.split(SPLIT)).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray());
        }
    }
```

And Finally, *THE ERROR I GET WHEN THOSE LINES ARE NOT COMMENTED OUT*:

```
OLD ERROR MESSAGES. SEE EDIT
```

Another Note, which might or might not be related to this is that SOMETIMES the bufferreader does not read the whole Line, this is some of the output I get (with those lines commented out and no errors)

```
Setting testInProgress to true 
 24.552  24.505  24.515  24.413  
24.457  24.435  24.354  24.433  24.510  24.553  24.506  24.515  24.413  
24.458  24.435  24.355  24.433  24.511  24.554  24.507  24.515  24.413  
24.458  24.436  24.355  24.433  24.511  24.554  24.507  24.515  24.413  
Test stopped by user! 
OK
```

Now you see, after the testInProgress is set to true the first line is INCOMPLETE (it should be 9 readings). I'm only getting the partial last half of the previous line, I dont know if this might be the reason why but even so they should still be able to get parsed.

*EDIT*
I modified the code as follows:

```
public class TemperatureParser {
    public TemperatureReading parse (String text) {
        System.out.println("String received: " + text);
        if (text != null && text.length() > 0)
        {
        return new TemperatureReading(Stream.of(text.split(SPLIT)).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray());
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Null reading");
        return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This at least lets me know the parser is getting a full string line and that its working. Also modified the eventlistener as follows: (added a check for 72 characters which are the 9 readings)

```
if (testProgress == true)
            {
                 try
                {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    fullLine = reader.readLine();
                    if (fullLine.length() == 72)
                    {
                        textLog.appendText(fullLine + "\n");
                        reading = parser.parse(fullLine);
                        readings.add(reading);

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                statusLabel.setText("@serialEvent.IF Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")");
                System.out.println("@SerialEvent.IF Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")");
                }
```

with this new code I get less errors, so I'm thinking I'm on the right track:

```
testProgress is True
String received: 25.360  25.371  25.254  25.342  25.545  25.609  25.501  25.527  25.444  
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
@SerialEvent.IF Failed to read data. (java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:236)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
    at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
    at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)
    at at.qcresponsetime.FXMLDocumentController.serialEvent(FXMLDocumentController.java:602)
    at gnu.io.RXTXPort.sendEvent(RXTXPort.java:772)
    at gnu.io.RXTXPort.eventLoop(Native Method)
    at gnu.io.RXTXPort$MonitorThread.run(RXTXPort.java:1641)
String received: 25.362  25.371  25.255  25.346  25.547  25.608  25.498  25.527  25.446  
@SerialEvent.IF Failed to read data. (java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String)
String received: 25.363  25.371  25.256  25.350  25.548  25.607  25.495  25.526  25.448  
@SerialEvent.IF Failed to read data. (java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String)
String received: 25.365  25.371  25.257  25.355  25.550  25.607  25.493  25.526  25.450  
@SerialEvent.IF Failed to read data. (java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String)
String received: 25.365  25.371  25.258  25.355  25.550  25.607  25.493  25.526  25.450  
@SerialEvent.IF Failed to read data. (java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String)
String received: 25.365  25.372  25.258  25.355  25.550  25.607  25.493  25.527  25.450  
@SerialEvent.IF Failed to read data. (java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String)
String received: 25.365  25.372  25.258  25.355  25.550  25.607  25.494  25.527  25.450  
@SerialEvent.IF Failed to read data. (java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String)
testProgress is False
Stop Button pressed!
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a `NumberFormatException`. This means you are trying to parse a string into a integer, and there's some kind of error in the process. My best guess is that the variable `fullLine` is giving you an empty string, so try adding an if surrounding :

```
reading = parser.parse(fullLine);
readings.add(reading);
```

checking if `fullLine` is empty, apart of checking it's length.
As far as I can see, the error tells you the string is empty, so just test printing that variable on different spots of your code.

Comment: I did try that, if you look at the output code and the source code as well I have a System.out.println "String Received: xxxxx" and basically there I check if I received a string thats not null and not empty. however I do still get that error for some reason